# How come GKE gives me different IPs for each ingress that I create?

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I am using multiple ingresses resource on my GKE, say I have 2 ingress in different namespaces. I create the ingress resource as shown in the yaml below. With the annotations used in the below yaml, I clearly mention that I am using the GCE controller that comes with GKE(https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce). But every time I create an ingress I get different IPs, For instance sometimes I get 133.133.133.***133*** and for the other times I get 133.133.133.***134***. And it alternates between only these two IPs (it's probably between only two IPs because of quotas limit). This is a problem when I just want to reserve one IP and load balance/terminate multiple apps on this IP only.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce
  name: http-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: http-svc
    servicePort: 80
```

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/276#issuecomment-279795653 - this is one of the reasons why I prefer using nginx based ingress

Comment: @MaciekSawicki Thanks for pointing out the above link.

Answer (score 1):

In your Ingress resource you can specify you need the Load Balancer to use a specific IP address with the `kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name` annotation like so:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: static-ip-name
  name: http-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: http-svc
    servicePort: 80
```

You will need to create a global static IP first using the gcloud tool. See step 2(b) here: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip.

Comment: I agree that the annotation you mentioned gives me a static IP. But suppose I try to use this same annotation(with same ip name) on another ingress(in same or different namespace). The other ingress does not have a same IP(rather in this case it does not get an IP at all because its already assigned) which is unlike nginx controller. In my opinion this is not good because obviously I would like to expose services in different namespace using the same IP. I expect GLBC in GKE to be more flexible.